# PHP - One application installation for multiple subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, wildcard-subdomain

I want to archive this **username.mydomain.com** for each new user register with application and each user has its own database.

Its actually inventory application developed in **codeigniter**, so user registration will be only done by admin.

One application installation for all sub domain(usersname) should points to same server directory, later application will select database according to subdomain so how can i archive this.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need to access same directory with different subdomain using wilcard-subdomain

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you want, is to follow the following steps:

1. DNS Configuration
2. Apache Configuration
3. Testing out your server configuration
4. Setting up CodeIgniter
5. Creating controllers & Views
6. Extending created controllers

All of the steps are nicely detailed in Atchyut Sekhar's article on tutsplus.com @ https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter--net-16330

Hope that helps!

Best,

-Rush